# Bug when randomizing angle between 0 and 2pi (also program stops responding with long drawing loop)

Tags: python, random, pygame

I'm trying to write a small program to illustrate the idea of the mean free path of a photon in a two dimensional star using pygame. I'm new to python in general (This is my 8th week of playing with python) and have only just started to experiment in pygame.

Essentially what my program is supposed to do is have a line start at the center of a circle and move some length 'l' before it turns a random amount of radians and goes another length 'l' and will repeat this until it hits the edge of the circle.

I'm having problems with the angle randomizing. Currently I've employed random.uniform() between 0 and 2pi, but I've noticed the line likes to progress almost straight downwards every time. Any help or suggestions for this problem would be appreciated.

Line 15 is where I define the angle to be used for the next line, also I've noticed if my path length 'l' is low enough the program will stop responding before finishing. I'm sure there's a simple explanation for this that I'm just unaware of, but if someone knows why that might be I would love to know.

Edit: The first problem was pointed out by schwobaseggl, I had wrote the wrong variable in for the change in my y coordinate in line 16. I still haven't figured out why the program stops responding after it draws for a little while though.

My code so far:

```
import pygame
import random
import math

def mfp():
    Rho = float(input('Enter average density: '))
    K = float(input('Enter opacity: '))
    l = 1/(K * Rho)
    return l

def line(l, screen):
    a = [250, 250]
    n = 0
    while ((a[0]-250)**2)+((a[1]-250)**2) < 220**2:
        ang = random.uniform(0, 2*math.pi)
        print(ang)
        #changed sin(l) to sin(ang)
        b = [a[0]+l*math.cos(ang), a[1]+l*math.sin(ang)]
        pygame.draw.line(screen, [255, 255, 255], a, b, 1)
        a = b
        pygame.display.flip()
        print('2') #debug

def vis():
    size = [500, 500]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [255, 255, 255], [250, 250], 220)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, [0, 0, 0], [250, 250], 219)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print('1') #debug
    return screen


def stop():
    done = False
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
    pygame.quit()



def main():
    line(mfp(), vis())
    stop()

main()
```

Comment: Did you try it with a random value between 0 and 360? :) if your line always goes in one direction, maybe that is the convention?
... I can't try your code, since I don't find this pygame package for python above version 2.5

Comment: I did try 360 initially with the same results, however when I went to change it to degrees to try it again I noticed I had been finding sin(l) instead of sin(ang) for my y value displacement. So I guess I solved my own problem haha I've spent two hours tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: If an answer has sufficiently resolved your problem, consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is this line:

```
b = [a[0]+l*math.cos(ang), a[1]+l*math.sin(l)]
```

Surely, you want `math.sin(ang)` here.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, I had just noticed that a few moments ago too. Thank you for the speedy reply!